# I just got Mortarboard ... on Meta?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, meta

[Yo.](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/badges/144/mortarboard?userid=6066)

Obviously Meta still has rep, it's just hidden.  I'd call this a bug though since I was notified of it and it shows up in [my activity](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/6066/matthew-read?tab=activity&sort=badges) and so on, which is not exactly hidden.

Comment: Hey, would you look at that, I'm still the first one with it.

Comment: See [Should I really have been awarded mortarboard on a Per-site meta?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78603/should-i-really-have-been-awarded-mortarboard-on-a-per-site-meta)

Answer (score 2):

This is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign). From Jeff on [Should I really have been awarded mortarboard on a Per-site meta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/79968/149432):

> Just redefine it as "you received a *lot* of upvotes in a single day". So I think it is correct in spirit.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, there is rep, just not shown.

Badges take this hidden rep into account in their calculation.